# How to add only new row from one table to another table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, hana, linked-server

I am using Linked Server in SQL Server which is connected to hana database. I want to import one table from hana database and make copy into sql. I have done the importing part. Now issue is that i want to make a query that  select the only row or insert only row in sql which is not existing or new. But my query is giving an error of Primary key violation which means its inserting all data again.
Here is my Query:

```
insert into OACT ( AcctCode,AcctName,CurrTotal,FatherNum,SysTotal,CreateDate,UpdateDate,ActId,FormatCode)
select tab2.AcctCode,tab2.AcctName,tab2.CurrTotal, tab2.FatherNum,tab2.SysTotal,tab2.CreateDate,tab2.UpdateDate,tab2.ActId,tab2.FormatCode
from HanaSql8.."TRAININGDB"."OACT" tab2
Where NOT EXISTS (
    Select tab1.AcctCode,tab1.AcctName,tab1.CurrTotal, tab1.FatherNum,tab1.SysTotal,tab1.CreateDate,tab1.UpdateDate,tab1.ActId,tab1.FormatCode
    from OACT  tab1
    where tab1.AcctCode=tab2.AcctCode
);
```

Comment: If you have a primary key, whats with the select list in the not exists clause?

Comment: Maybe you can share the exact error message so we can have a better idea

Comment: @Eralper Error : Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__OACT__21B5C07FC7D71CE9'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.OACT'. The duplicate key value is (_SYS00000000111).

Comment: Primary key is AcctCode

Comment: Maybe your source data has dublicate values for AcctCode. Is it also PK in HANA database? And if you have mandt fields, maybe you should filter the correct SAP client in source data

Comment: @Eralper I have inserted 556 rows one time. So error should be there at that time as well. But when I add where not exists clause to add only new row  this error occurs

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work without any problem if the primary key on target table is defined on AcctCode column

In EXISTS() or NOT EXISTS() you don't have to select with column names, it is only a logical check so you can modify as follows

```
insert into OACT ( 
    AcctCode,AcctName,CurrTotal,
    FatherNum,SysTotal,CreateDate
    ,UpdateDate,ActId,FormatCode
    )
select 
    tab2.AcctCode,tab2.AcctName,tab2.CurrTotal, 
    tab2.FatherNum,tab2.SysTotal,tab2.CreateDate,
    tab2.UpdateDate,tab2.ActId,tab2.FormatCode
from HanaSql8.."TRAININGDB"."OACT" tab2
Where NOT EXISTS (
    Select *
    from OACT  tab1
    where tab1.AcctCode=tab2.AcctCode
);
```

We can test LEFT JOIN clause as an alternative to NOT EXISTS()

Here is the query

```
insert into OACT ( 
    AcctCode,AcctName
)
select 
    tab2.AcctCode,tab2.AcctName
from HanaSql8.."TRAININGDB"."OACT" tab2
left join OACT tab1
    on tab1.AcctCode=tab2.AcctCode
where tab1.AcctCode is null
```

Comment: primary key is AcctCode but still its giving an error: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__OACT__21B5C07FC7D71CE9'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.OACT'. The duplicate key value is (_SYS00000000111).
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Do you have already this value '_SYS00000000111' in your SQL Server database table? If not, it means the source hana db table has dublicates in it

Comment: yes i already have this value in my SQL Server. which means the where clause is not working in my case

Comment: I added a second query with LEFT JOIN to eliminate the existing entries in target table

Comment: shahzaib, just try to execute the LEFT JOIN query without INSERT part and without WHERE clause. In SELECT list add tab1.AcctCode, tab2.AcctCode and other fields from both tables. There you will see all data from source (HANA db) and from target (SQLServer DB). Then we can add filter conditions accordingly

Comment: Can you identify a criteria to seperate new data from existing one on SQL database?

Comment: do you have an email?